# How to upload multiple pdf file to Manufacturer in magento 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, ce-1.9.1.1, manufacturer

How to upload multiple pdf file with manufacturers in magento 1.9.1.1, I have use this [plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo.html) for upload manufacturer logo but I want to upload multiple pdf also